# Obstacles Javascript Snake

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have made a Snake game, and I want to add bushes that the snake is not allowed to touch. The bushes needs to be places in lines throughout the map.

I have added a single bush, but I dont know how to do something as simpel as copy pasting the bush but movin it underneath the existing. I'm thinking i need a for loop of some kind. But I really dont know how to implement it.

```
<script>
var wall;
var wall_y;
var wall_x;
var frameCount = 0;
const FRAME_COUNT_NEW_LINE = 500;
function bush() {

    ctx.dra
}
function doWall() {

if (inGame) {
    ctx.drawImage(wall, wall_x, wall_y);
    for (var z = 0; z < dots; z++) {

        if (z == 0) {
            ctx.drawImage(head, x[z], y[z]);
        } else {
            ctx.drawImage(ball, x[z], y[z]);
        }
    }  console.log(wall_y); 
       console.log(wall_x);
    console.log(apple_x);
    console.log(apple_y);
 } else {
     gameOver();
}        
}
//Is there collision?
function checkWall() {
if ((x[0] == wall_x) && (y[0] == wall_y)) {
    locateWall();
    gameOver();
}
}
//Where is the wall?
function locateWall() {
wall_x = 5 * DOT_SIZE;
wall_y = 30 * DOT_SIZE;

}
```